# Why take minimum of left , diagonal and top matrix values in case of finding maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I was going through the dynamic Problem of finding the "maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix" .I am not able to understand why take minimum value instead of maximum value for the adjacent columns . It will be a great help if someone help me understand how this solution has been derived . 
The problem is as follows : 
Given a binary matrix, find out the maximum size square sub-matrix with all 1s.
The recommended solution is :

```
1) Construct a sum matrix S[R][C] for the given M[R][C].
         a)    Copy first row and first columns as it is from M[][] to S[][]
         b)    For other entries, use following expressions to construct S[][]
             If M[i][j] is 1 then
                S[i][j] = min(S[i][j-1], S[i-1][j], S[i-1][j-1]) + 1
             Else /*If M[i][j] is 0*/
                S[i][j] = 0
    2) Find the maximum entry in S[R][C]
    3) Using the value and coordinates of maximum entry in S[i], print 
       sub-matrix of M[][]
```

Comment: Please share the problem description directly in the question, without putting an image

Comment: You are looking for a SQUARE matrix so if the results is 2 x 4 the square is 2 x 2.

Comment: So , in case if we need to find the rectangular matrix, then we will take the maximum of the left , top and diagonal columns .